# Prove, that $a^2 + d^2 \ge b^2 + c^2$

Tags: logic

I am searching for a proof of a random exercise i found on my iPad. I can't remeber why and when I wanted to solve this... This one got me and now I try to solve it, but I don't get it done.

Given $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{b}{c} = \frac{c}{d}$, then prove that $a^2+d^2≥b^2+c^2$. I am not sure if more information was given. I assume that $a<b<c<d$. (Would the proof be different if I didn't assume $a<b<c<d$?)

My attempt was:

Since $ac=b^2$, $bd=c^2$ and $ad=cb$, I can write $b^2+c^2=ad+cb<dd+cb=d^2+cb$.

Unfortunately $cb>a$, so I can't replace that correctly. With these appraisals I don't get it done. For me it seems to be way harder.

Can you help me?

Comment: avoid asking help me questions in first place, I have answered it because you didn't even know what the actual question was, Rather try to give more attempts before even asking hints for such questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{c}{d}=k$

Now
$a=bk$, $b=ck$, $c=dk$

Putting values, $c=dk$, $b=dk^2$, $a=dk^3$

now assume $a^2+d^2 < b^2+c^2$

hence

$d^2k^6+d^2 < d^2k^4+d^2k^2$

as $d$ is not zero

it follows

$k^6+1 < k^4+k^2$

which in turn is

$k^6-k^2 < k^4-1$

it follows

$(k^2-1)(k^4-1) < 0$

$(k^2-1)^2(k^2+1) < 0$

As L.H.S is always non-negative, Our assumption is wrong

hence proved by contradiction that

$a^2+d^2≥b^2+c^2$

Comment: This would read much nicer as a direct proof IMHO: $a^2+d^2-b^2-c^2 = \cdots = (k^2-1)(k^4-1)d^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: @MartinR, I agree, I didn't think of it at the time of writing the answer

Comment: jep, read that answer and tried myself after some days! very nice, thank you!